# my date inputs chosen with datepicker are not inserting into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datepicker

Im doing an insert with PDO that it seems correct for me, and the insert is working.

But the date_begin and date_end info is not inserting, my table receivs in this fields the value of :"0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000".

Im using datepicker to choose date.

Do you see what Can be wrong? I dont receive any error or notice!

**My insert with pdo:**

```
$insertEvent = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, level, date_begin, date_end) VALUES (:title, :level, :date_begin, :date_end)");  
$insertEvent->bindValue(':title', $f['tile']);
$insertEvent->bindValue(':level', $f['level']);
$insertEvent->bindValue(':date_begin', $f['date_begin']);
$insertEvent->bindValue(':date_end', $f['date_end']);
$insertEvent->execute();          
   echo'Sucess';
```

If I print this variables, they have the right data that I choose in date picker:

```
echo $f['date_begin'];
echo $f['date_end'];
```

**My form:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label>
            <span>Title:</span>
            <input type="text"  name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])) echo $f['title']; ?>" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span class="data">Begin Date:</span>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date_begin" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date_begin'])) echo $f['date_begin']; ?>" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span>End Date:</span>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date_end" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date_end'])) echo $f['date_end']; ?>" />
        </label>

         <label>
           <span>Select the level:</span>
            <select name="level">
            <option value="">Select the user level;</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>        
            </select>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="sendForm" />

    </form>
```

Comment: You have `:data_fim` which doesn't match what you're trying to put in, which seems to be related to `bindValue(':date_end', $f['date_end']);` that most likely should be `(:title, :level, :date_begin, :date_end)` - Having error reporting on http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php would have caught that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was doing the translation here and I forget to change that parameter, sorry! But In my example here I have correct and now I update my question!

Comment: You're welcome. I figured that `data fim` meant `end date` in a certain language. Which language is it, am curious?

Comment: Also make sure your columns are of the correct type. `DATETIME` or similar.

Comment: I have my columns as TimeStamp! And yes, means end date, and data fim its portuguese language :)

Comment: You would most probably need to change your column type to `DATETIME`. As for the language, cool. `fim` and `fin` are closely related to many Latin-origin languages, which brought me to think that's what it meant. ;-)

Comment: Its not working also with datetime, and the datepicker format is like "04/30/2014" and datetime is "0000-00-00". So maybe this is reallty the problem! And yes, portuguese language have influences of latin and so we have many of similar words with other languages

Comment: Ah, that's most likely why then. You need to try and switch it around so that's it's `Y-M-D` instead of `M-D-Y` - Notice the 4x `0000` then the other 2x `00`? Your date is the opposite.

Comment: Keep me posted if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was really whay you said, I solve the problem formatting my datepicker with jQuery, I added this: dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd" and it worked fine! Thank you :)

Comment: That's great, glad to hear it. Let me know if you want me to post it as an answer in order to close the question.

Comment: Yes, for me it is ok :)

Comment: It has been done, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its not working also with datetime, and the datepicker format is like "04/30/2014" and datetime is "0000-00-00". So maybe this is reallty the problem!

You need to switch it around so that's it's Y-M-D instead of M-D-Y

Notice the 4x `0000`'s then the other 2x `00`'s? Your date is the opposite.